# Задача на массивы

Tags: c++, массивы, динамические-массивы, олимпиада

Задача C. Похожие массивы
(Время: 1 сек. Память: 16 Мб Баллы: 100)
Два массива называются похожими, если совпадают множества чисел, встречающихся в этих массивах.

Требуется написать программу, которая определит: похожи ли два заданных массива.

Входные данные
Входной файл INPUT.TXT содержит в первой строке два числа M и N - длины массивов (1 ≤ M, N ≤ 16000). Во второй строке записаны M чисел – элементы первого массива. В третьей строке записаны N чисел – элементы второго массива. Числа в строках разделены пробелами, элементы массивов - целые числа, не превышающие 32000 по абсолютной величине.

Выходные данные
Выходной файл OUTPUT.TXT должен содержать 1, если массивы похожи и 0 иначе.

```
int main()
{

int n, k;

cin >> n >> k;

int *p = new int[n];

int *b = new int[k];

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cin >> p[i];

for(int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    cin >> b[i];

bool f;

for(int i = 0; i < k; i++)
{
    f = (p[i] == b[i]);
}

if (f)
    cout << 1;
else
    cout << 0;
}
```

попробовал так решить не получилось

Comment: Похожи или идентичны?

Comment: @Maggot И вы туда же? Где тут слово идентичны, кроме как в вашем вопросе? :)

Comment: @Harry Я просто спрашиваю) в вопросе вообще файл, а в коде std::cin и std::cout )))) все решают разные задачи) нет проверки ни на 16000 ни на 32000.....

Comment: @Maggot Какие проверки в олимпиадном программировании?! См. https://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=522

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так проще:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int M,N;
    set<int> a,b;
    cin >> M >> N;
    for(int x; M --> 0;)
    {
        cin >> x; a.insert(x);
    }
    for(int x; N --> 0;)
    {
        cin >> x; b.insert(x);
    }

    cout << (a == b) << endl;
}
```

Comment: причем тут set?  Задается константный порядок элементов, их нельзя переставлять, и потом  `std::set<int>{1, 5, 24, 34,  44} != std::set<int>{1, 5, 24}`, однако эти массивы считаются похожими...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan "*если совпадают множества чисел, встречающихся в этих массивах*" - при чем тут порядок? А вообще - засуньте этот код [сюда](https://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=522) и убедитесь, что он работает... То, что вы привели - никак не похоже, а вот `1,2,5,9,2,6` и `1,2,5,6,9` - и в самом деле похожи.

Comment: мне не нужно проверять такой простой код, но он будет работать далеко не всегда верно, потому что  приведенные вами множества не должны выдавать ответ, что похожи, потому что, в частности  4 _ тый  и 5 _ тый элементы отличаются

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Ну что ж я могу поделать, если ваше представление об условиях задачи отличается от того, что в него вложили авторы? :) Не всегда мир вокруг (и задачи :)) такой, каким мы хотим его видеть... Только вот мое решение тесты проходит (подтверждается принятием автором вопроса :)), а ваш - увы... Где посмотреть - я вам написал.

Comment: Похожи или идентичны?

Comment: @Harry,      https://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=522

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Именно. Мое решение его прошло. Ваше... Знаете, проверьте сами. Я-то проверил и его, но вы уж сами.

Comment: @Harry информация с сайта подтверждает задачу, вопрос где проверки и логи профилировки?

Comment: @Maggot Блин. Что вы хотите? Возьмите решение, отправьте на проверку и убедитесь, что оно работает. Какие еще логи я вам должен дать?

Comment: @Harry тише...тише )))) я просто докапываюсь)

Comment: Условие задачи понимается неоднозначно, поэтому появляются разногласия, в любом случаи, это не технический вопрос, чтобы в нем углубляться...

Comment: @Harry можно было просто указать что макс сайз - 16000, 2 контейнера. на таком то компиляторе это столько памяти что в в столько раз меньше 16 мб.

Answer (score 0):

В задании нет условия, что массивы должны быть упорядочены или их элементы должны быть уникальны. 
Если не пользоваться стандартными алгоритмами или контейнерами, то второй массив вовсе не нужен для вывода ответа, а нужно лишь сравнивать каждое вводимое число с элементами уже инициализированного массива.

```
int M, N;
std::cin >> M >> N;    
int* numbers = new int[M];
for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i)
    cin >> numbers[i];
bool b = true;
int n,  i = 0;
//сначала проверяем первое соответствие
while (cin >> n && (n != numbers[i++]) && i < M && i < N);

//проверяем соответствие остальных элементов
//если в диапазоне хоть один не соответствуе, то не похожи
for (int j = i; j < M && j < N; ++j) {
    cin >> n;
    if (n != numbers[j]) {
        b = false;
        break;
    }
}    
cout << b;
delete []numbers;
```

Comment: У вас похожесть это не похожесть из условия а индентичность, если я правильно понял ваш код.

Comment: @Mikhailo,  идентичные массивы не могут иметь разное количество элементов